# How to animate semicircle-like meter indicating elapsed time with HTML/CSS/JS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am looking for a solution for how to go about animating the following image indicating elapsed time as you see below. To make it easier for explanatory purposes, I would like the animation to take place in 10% intervals (despite me showing the 67% image example.) In effect, the colored gradient you see in the meter would be revealed and perhaps unmasked at these different 10% intervals to show more of the colored gradient. Could I employ some sort of masking technique with a `<div>` and perhaps some CSS3 transforms? I have this image in different layers in PhotoShop so it is definitely possible for me to manipulate the elements. How should I go about doing this?

This is what it looks like at 67% complete:
[image]

..and 100% complete:
[image]

Comment: How so if the assets are in PhotoShop?

Comment: You would recreate them from scratch using CSS properties (gradients & shadows)

Comment: I think this option is going to be too time consuming unfortunately at this point in the project...

Comment: You can use canvas for this as well. There are a load of examples on the web for this.

Comment: You might be able to turn each layer into a background image.

Comment: is making 10 images, a data-value attrib, and 10 lines of CSS too much hand-coding? it should be pretty easy at that point. css sprites can git rid of 9 images...

Comment: You could try see the code that makes the 'cpu usage' in this theme http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0135486 and learn how make the canvas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some ways to do it.

The most used lately are with JS and canvas, but there are pure CSS3 methods too.
All of these I will post use a complete circle but in your case, you can use as base and edit them to your needs.

JS/Canvas:

- http://p.ar2oor.pl/cprogress/
- http://anthonyterrien.com/knob/

CSS3:

- http://fromanegg.com/post/41302147556/100-pure-css-radial-progress-bar
- http://www.alessioatzeni.com/blog/css3-loading-animation-loop/

For more results, google 'css radial progress bar'.